# SPS 2013 List view shows all the required columns but with edit icon option

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, css, edit

SPS 2013 List view shows all the required columns but with edit icon option.
I want the user to click on the first column so they can open the associated content in a separate page to view all in detailed.
But I don't want the option to edit, that gives the user option to create new or modify the existing.

Well I tried to disable the same via CSS, but the movement cursor is rollover any of the list item, the Edit icon option would appear again.

Comment: Interesting, I was able to disable the edit options. But for whatever reason the Header text for each column doesn't appear. Tried changing - background, 
- color,

Not sure what it takes to modifying the color for the text rather the field?

Comment: Why doesn't disabling it in the List View settings help? (disable the Edit column, and uncheck Tabular view)

Comment: @DannyEngelmanNVP disabling the edit column, will lead to not allow to click on the item to open in modal view.